# GNU Radio does not work expectedly when the frequency is 2x the sample rate

Tags: software-defined-radio, gnuradio, frequency

Simple flow in GNU Radio 3.8.2.0 (Python 3.9.2).

[image: 1k.png]
If `samp rate` is 32k, when `Frequency` moves to 64k the recovered `cosine` wave disappeared.

What's more, when I reduce `Frequency` to `32k` I cannot get `cosine` wave, and `cosine` wave appeared when I increase `Frequency` to `33k`.

[image: Screenshot-from-2022-03-05-03-52-50.png]

What's the problem?

Comment: I wonder what happens if you decrease the frequency to just below 25% of the sample rate?

Comment: @jdv,become traingle wave.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't this just an example of the Nyquist Limit? Do you get your expected results if the sample rate is something like 4x the frequency?

Comment: `samp rate` is  `32k`,then I should get expect cosine wave when `frequency`  <= `64k`.Is that right?

Comment: More like "If a function x(t) contains no frequencies higher than B hertz, it is completely determined by giving its ordinates at a series of points spaced 1/(2B) seconds apart." Which means you can't just sample with 1/2 the f.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm reasonably sure that you are running into the limits defined by the Shannon-Nyquist sampling theorem.

There is a [GNU Radio tutorial](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php?title=Sample_Rate_Tutorial) on this subject that is basically your block diagram with a sine wave fed into time and frequency domain sinks. In fact, it would be a good idea to study the [GNU Radio Suggested Reading](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php?title=SuggestedReading).

The idea is that as the frequency increases, so too must your sample rate. Because otherwise you will get artefacts like aliasing, and at some point you will not be able to recover *any* of the signal you are sampling. Which seems to be exactly what you are seeing here.

Take a look at your frequency domain graph as you bump the frequency higher. You'll see it wander from the input frequency as you experience aliasing until you reach the limit where you can't even recover anything at all.

Comment: I think it's a question can be  reproduced. Anywhere I broke nyquist limit?

Comment: Definitely look at the tutorial I linked to. You can literally see how the limit is reached and how that affects the time and frequency domain graphs. The constellation graph is literally missing all the data points at high enough *f*.

Comment: Per your reference link,when `samp rate` is 32k(big enough),why `frequency` 1.8k cause aliasing?Is that gnuradio's problem or I miss something?

Comment: Sorry, I confused both of us. I'll edit my answer. You'll see aliases as you approach 1/2 the sample rate. This is the nature of sampling in the real world.

Comment: in the real world,I know nothing about the interested signal,how to totally avoid aliasing?

Comment: That is a large and complicated subject that requires someone smarter than me, and probably another question! I'd hack on the tutorials a bit to make I understand how the math is modelled in GRC. There is one tutorial that shows how you can adjust the sample rate via interpolation. But, handling the messy fact that sampling is frequency dependant is one of the reasons _good_ SDR design is _hard_.

Comment: @kittygirl this is not a GNU Radio issue: you really need to understand the *basics* of digital signal processing. This is *really* basics, and it's covered in the tutorials, at least superficially. You can't solve your lack of skills through asking – you will need to read a book or at least do the tutorials more diligently, I'm afraid. Otherwise, this will continually be very frustrating to you :(

Comment: @kittygirl hook up a QT GUI Range to the Frequency of the input Source and move the slider while you inspect the Time and Frequency domains. It is not a _bug_ when the sampled frequency jumps to a negative number, or the amplitude eventually goes constant. These are artefacts of DSP when a signal is deeply undersampled.