# How to know whether aliasing occurs when observe unknown signal?

Tags: software-defined-radio, signal-identification, dsp, spectrum-analyzer

Per [my good but downvote question](https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/20656/20457),I am hard to set sample rate even to a standard cosine wave.
When I observe unkwon signal,how to judge whether aliasing occurs?

Comment: I suspect that this is already well-covered on DSP StackExchange. Well, aspects of it will be. Consider that undersampling in order to deliberately use the aliasing to recover a frequency band is a typical DSP activity.

Comment: Your previous question was *not* good, in that it assumed something was broken about the tool you're using, wheras, as a beginner who knows the math basics aren't fully understood by you, you should assume that it's a matter fo *understanding your tool*. (jdv thankfully edited the question to fix that, as far as possible.) That humility, but an optimism that you can learn, is a very important mindset when learning things. If you always assume *others* do broken things (as your numpy questions on SE also do), then you'll never be able to understand!

Comment: To help you understand why people downvoted things, in hopes it helps you not only ask better questions, but also make progress of your own: Downvotes on SE mean "this question was not properly researched by the asker themselves, or makes unexplained assumptions, is confused". That's exactly why I also downvoted this question: jdv's answer to your previous question, **in the first sentence** gives you the term to research, **Shannon-Nyquist Sampling Theorem**. You haven't done **any** research, or at least you don't show it. We can't put knowledge in your brain, you have to do that yourself!

Comment: I don't want to pile-on, but I _urge_ you to visit https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php?title=SuggestedReading and spend some time studying the **free** material there. I'll admit your questions have prompted me to invest a bit more time doing my own research, so thank you for that. But a good question here will show what research you have done. Good questions about GNU Radio, DSP, and SDR will assume you have spent your own time studying the many, many resources out there.

Comment: Very apropos: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/82968

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This question may not be on-topic for Amateur Radio SE, given that it is about general DSP (for which there is already a StackExchange). I'll accept the community consensus on whether this is better suited for DSP.SE.*

> When we sample a 5500 Hz signal at 10,000 frames per second, the
> result is **indistinguishable** from a 4500 Hz signal. For the same
> reason, a 7700 Hz signal is **indistinguishable** from 2300 Hz, and a 9900
> Hz is **indistinguishable** from 100 Hz.

*"Think DSP", Allen B. Downey* (Emphasis mine)

However, in terms of practicality for making a general purpose SDR thing with (probably) GNU Radio, we can offer two practical answers:

1. Know that sampling is frequency dependent, and choose your sample rate accordingly. It isn't common to not know anything about the frequency ranges you are *intending* to sample. Though, you *must* understand [what sample rate means in GNU Radio](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/FAQ#What_does_sample_rate_mean_in_GNU_Radio?) first!
2. Use anti-aliasing (low-pass) filters to remove unwanted high frequency components to preserve the information to some bandwidth suitable for your application.

(2) will not help your trivial case, where you are simply feeding a high-frequency pure signal into a sampler that has reached its Nyquist limit. But AA filters are real-world tools used on the front-end of many systems to make sure that high frequency spikes don't introduce aliasing and other artefacts later on in the processing chain. Any system is going to be designed with some target signals in mind, and AA filters allow you to set some guarantees that at least you won't start getting junk data because suddenly your sampling rate is too low.

Like I said, DSP SE might have more insight -- I'm no DSP engineer -- but my understanding is that if you can invent a system to determine the actual frequency of some input beyond the Nyquist limit you better patent that idea quick. But I have no doubt that there are some clever workarounds for detecting if we are in an unintended under-sampling situation.

Not strictly about recovering information in these edge situations, but you can also consider sample rate interpolation. This might be helpful in some cases because it allows you to have weighted filtering for recovering bandwidth-suitable signals.

A final note: *none* of this is specific to radio or recovering information from RF energy. From a DSP perspective, sampling, information recovery, interpolation, and AA filtering are basic building blocks for *any* signal you want to process.

Comment: This has been my experience when doing basic DSP on signals for work. If I don't know a-priori something about the signal characteristics then it's impossible to do QC.